# Does HABTM jointable needs index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, indexing, migration

Is it necessary to add_index on HABTM join table? I use t.belongs_to (aka t.references). Here is code

```
class CreateCohortsUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    create_table :cohorts_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :cohort
      t.belongs_to :user
    end
    add_index :cohorts_users, :cohort_id # Do I need this?
    add_index :cohorts_users, :user_id  # Do I need this?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to add a unique index on both columns:

```
add_index :cohorts_users, [:cohort_id, :user_id], unique: true
```